# Loading different screens for different types of users in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, session

I have two types of users and I need to save the authorization session after close the app

I use Firebase and I added a bool variable to determine whether the user is "authorized" or not

When I launch the app again, I check the status.

In the code below, I can register as a "client," if the application is closed and then opened again, everything will work well

`home: isLoggedIn ? const RegScreenWidget() : const StartScreenClientWidget(),`

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

import 'package:geomap/screen/login_screen_client.dart';
import 'package:geomap/screen/logni_screen_company.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  
  bool isLoggedIn = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    checkStatusUser();
    super.initState();
  }

  void checkStatusUser() {
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null) {
      isLoggedIn = true;
    } else {
      isLoggedIn = false;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Promo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.lime,
      ),
      routes: {
        '/main': (context) => const RegScreenWidget(),
        '/start_screen_company': (context) => const StartScreenCompanyWidget(),
        '/start_screen_client': (context) => const StartScreenClientWidget(),
      },
      home: isLoggedIn ? const RegScreenWidget() : const StartScreenClientWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class RegScreenWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegScreenWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<RegScreenWidget> createState() => _RegScreenWidgetState();
}

class _RegScreenWidgetState extends State<RegScreenWidget> {
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Registration'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Text(
                'Registration screen',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 200,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextField(
                      controller: _emailController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'email',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      controller: _passController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'pass',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: regCompany,
                child: const Text('Registration as a Company'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: regClient,
                child: const Text('Registration as a Client'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  const Text("I'm already registered,"),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('sign in'),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void regCompany() async {
    var _emailCompany = _emailController.text;

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: _emailController.text.trim(),
      password: _passController.text.trim(),
    );

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(_emailCompany)
        .set({
      'emailCompany': _emailCompany,
      'typeUser': 'company',
    });

    _emailController.clear();
    _passController.clear();

    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/start_screen_company');
  }

  void regClient() async {
    var _emailClient = _emailController.text;

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: _emailController.text.trim(),
      password: _passController.text.trim(),
    );

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(_emailClient).set({
      'emailCompany': _emailClient,
      'typeUser': 'client',
    });

    _emailController.clear();
    _passController.clear();

    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/start_screen_client');
  }
}
```

But I have two types of users and I need to show two different screens. If I register as a "company," close the application, then open again, there will be an error, because I need a screen for the company.

I use the Firebase and after registration, I create a table in which the "type" of the user is displayed

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT4zN.jpg)

I can check this data and use it: "client" or "company" is now authorized

How do I show different screens? I need a simple solution, I'm new and trying to understand the basic things.

My last full code, i have an error(

i think the screen loads faster than I get data on what type of user - authorized and I get an error, how i can change it?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

import 'package:geomap/screen/login_screen_client.dart';
import 'package:geomap/screen/logni_screen_company.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Map<String, Widget> screenByUser = {
    'client': const StartScreenClientWidget(),
    'company': const StartScreenCompanyWidget(),
  };

  var userType = '';

  bool notLogInUser = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    checkStatusUser();
    super.initState();
  }

  void checkStatusUser() async {
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null) {
      return;
    } else {
      notLogInUser = false;
      print('user is auth');
      var _emailUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email;
      var document =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(_emailUser);
      var snapshot = await document.get();
      Map<String, dynamic>? data = snapshot.data();
      var typeUserfromFBS = data!['typeUser'];
      print(typeUserfromFBS);
      userType = typeUserfromFBS;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Promo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.lime,
      ),
      routes: {
        '/main': (context) => const RegScreenWidget(),
        '/start_screen_company': (context) => const StartScreenCompanyWidget(),
        '/start_screen_client': (context) => const StartScreenClientWidget(),
      },
      home: notLogInUser ? const RegScreenWidget() : screenByUser[userType],
    );
  }
}

class RegScreenWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegScreenWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<RegScreenWidget> createState() => _RegScreenWidgetState();
}

class _RegScreenWidgetState extends State<RegScreenWidget> {
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Registration'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Text(
                'Registration screen',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 200,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextField(
                      controller: _emailController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'email',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      controller: _passController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'pass',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: regCompany,
                child: const Text('Registration as a Company'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: regClient,
                child: const Text('Registration as a Client'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                  },
                  child: Text('Go Out')),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  const Text("I'm already registered,"),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('sign in'),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void regCompany() async {
    var _emailCompany = _emailController.text;

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: _emailController.text.trim(),
      password: _passController.text.trim(),
    );

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(_emailCompany)
        .set({
      'emailCompany': _emailCompany,
      'typeUser': 'company',
    });

    _emailController.clear();
    _passController.clear();

    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/start_screen_company');
  }

  void regClient() async {
    var _emailClient = _emailController.text;

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: _emailController.text.trim(),
      password: _passController.text.trim(),
    );

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(_emailClient).set({
      'emailCompany': _emailClient,
      'typeUser': 'client',
    });

    _emailController.clear();
    _passController.clear();

    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/start_screen_client');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Map key as String (user type) and value as Widget based on user type. like below.

```
Map<String, Widget> screenByUser = {
 'client': StartScreenClientWidget(),
 'company': StartScreenCompanyWidget()
}
```

use below in the home

```
home: isLoggedIn ? const RegScreenWidget() : screenByUser['HERE_USER_TYPE'],
```

This might work other wise create one more screen to handle.

Comment: I added a new code, you can look at this ... and i have an error(